# Writing SQL Server view / query that takes another joined / generated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2017

Using SQL Server 2017, I have more or less the following data structures:

```
+------------+
|   Users    |
+------------+
| pk: UserID |
| ...        |
| ...        |
+------------+

+---------------+
|   Addresses   |
+---------------+
| pk: AddressId |
| AddressCode   |
| ...           |
| ...           |
+---------------+

+-------------------+
|   AddressTypes    | (Currently just 4 entries 1,2,3,4)
+-------------------+
| pk: AddressTypeId |
| Description       |
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
|   UserAddresses   |
+-------------------+
| fk: UserId        |
| fk: AddressId     |
| fk: AddressTypeId |
+-------------------+
```

What I'd like the query to return is UserId, AddressCode with following condition. 
I want the query to return me the AddressCode which has AddressTypeId 4. But if AddressTypeId 4 does not exist, the AddressCode which has AddressTypeId 3, if again it doesn't exist, AddressTypeId 2, if again it doesn't exist, AddressTypeId 1.

I would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: select the data, order by the addressType and take the first entry with `top 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` to find the highest type and then just filter the other ones out, as in:

```
select
  userid,
  addresscode
from (
  select
    ua.userid,
    a.addresscode,
    row_number() over(partition by ua.userid order by ua.addresstype desc) as rn
  from useraddresses ua
  join addresses a on a.addressid = ua.addressid
) x
where rn = 1
```